# Уникальный выпадающий список для каждого пользователя PHP

Tags: php

Как сделать так, что при регистрации будет создаваться новая таблица в бд привязанная к user_id, с шаблонными данными, а после авторизации на форме в выпадающих списках, данные брались из бд в соответствии с авторизированным пользователем? То есть зарегистрировался, создалась таблица, она заполнилась, после чего данные выгрузились в выпадающие списки, каждый столбец в свой выпадающий список.

Comment: Создавать таблицу под каждого юзера? Помойкой быстро станет ваша база...

Comment: а поле `user_id` в таблицу не судьба добавить?

Comment: Ну количество пользователей вряд ли перевалит за 30. А альтернативных вариантов я не знаю, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Ну и от нас-то вы чего хотите? Показать вам как делать запросы в mysql? Так этого добра в интернетиках тонны

Comment: Так а в чем проблема хранить всё в одной таблице?